# how to load google map in My site?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

my code is like this

```
<div id="map" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border:1px solid #000000; position:absolute">&nbsp;</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowMap(Longitude,Latitude,Address){
var map = new GMap(document.getElementById("map"));
map.centerAndZoom(new GPoint(Longitude,Latitude),2);
map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
var point = new GPoint(Longitude,Latitude);
}
</script>
<script language="javascript">ShowMap('73.15821','22.32316','')</script>        
</div>
```

in head tag

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=1&key=ABQIAAAAUbVoUU0NAYILZTXJsa42UhQAOjerBL9Cz5dE0cCceAtSlRyy8RSeV_tVtvvlVOxAL55LJfb2kwET3Q" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Error is

> ReferenceError: GMap is not defined
>   [Break On This Error]
>   var map = new GMap(document.getElementById("drctmap"));

Comment: It works fine here, nicely showing New IPCL Road, but you should really consider using api v3 instead.

Comment: are you using [Google Maps API V3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/)? Also, its not a good idea posting your api key

Comment: @kedmenot - `v=1` = API1

Answer (score 1):

You should execute the `showMap` function after the dom loads :

```
window.onload = function(){ShowMap('73.15821','22.32316',''));
```

Or how google is attaching the load event (as seen [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#LoadingMap)):

```
<body onload="ShowMap('73.15821','22.32316','');">
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because your document is not fully loaded when executing `ShowMap()`

Try wrapping your script into `document.onload` or `window.onload`.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a deprecated version of the Google Maps API. If you really were using version 3, you would simply use "Map" instead of "GMap" as a constructor...